# Get a FIRST value of json dictionary in python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary

I have json like this, in python.

```
{
    "unknown1": {
        "somekeys": "somevalues"
    }
    "unknown2": {
        "somekeys": "somevalues"
    }
    "unknown3": {
        "somekeys": "somevalues"
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get ONLY unknown1 dictionary?

Unknowns are really unknowns and are different each time. 
The speed of this operation is critical.

(I know how to load the json with json.loads)

Comment: Are you saying the keys are unknown? JSON is not ordered so there is no "first unknown key".

Comment: JSON objects are key-value pairs. Unless you want to sort the keys, there is no concept of "first key" in a JSON object.

Comment: About all you can do is iterate through all of the dictionary's keys and skip those that are known.

Comment: But isn't there a way to, maybe, iterate throu this json so it give me unknown1 dictionary on the first iteration or something like this? Or it would be as random as iterateing thru python dictionary?

Comment: Again: JSON objects are key-value pairs. There is no inherent concept of "first key". The same goes with dictionaries. If you want the keys in a specified order, then you will have to iterate through the `sorted` keys in the order in which you specify. Or use a different data structure (a list of dictionaries, perhaps?).

Answer (score 0):

### No, there is no way to do this

In the comments, you write:

> But isn't there a way to, maybe, iterate throu this json so it give me unknown1 dictionary on the first iteration or something like this? Or it would be as random as iterateing thru python dictionary?

That's exactly correct. When you load json into python using `json.load()` or `json.loads`, the json string is converted into a python `dict`. So, once it's loaded, you should treat it like any other `dict`, because it is one.

Answer (score -1):

try to use some loop system
like this

```
first_value
for i in JsonFile:
    first_value = i
    break
```

first_value is the first dictionary